# Run navsat_transform_node without odometry

Tags: ros2, odometry, imu, gps, navsat-transform-node

My (marine) robot has GNSS and and IMU, but no means to measure odometry (which is an estimate of local motion afaik)

I am looking for my robot's state expressed as tf2 in a predefined local, world-fixed reference frame.

I believed the navsat_transform_node could do this, but according to [the documentation](https://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/robot_localization/html/navsat_transform_node.html) it needs an sensor_msgs/Imu, sensor_msgs/NavSatFix and nav_msgs/Odometry inputs of which I miss the last.

Setting up the navsat_transform_node, while confirming streams on the imu and navsatfix topics yields no output on odometry/gps or /tf.

Theoretically it should be possible to use measured heading and gnss location to find a position in a local coordinate system, but I'm not managing.

Can the navsat_transform_node function without odometry input?
Thoughts and feedback on how I tackle this challenge are welcome

---

Ros version: Foxy

launch description part of the navsat_transform_node:

```
navsat_transform_node = Node(
    package='robot_localization',
    executable='navsat_transform_node',
    name='navsat_transform_node',
    namespace=vessel_id_value,
    remappings=[
        ('gps/fix','telemetry/gnss/fix'),
        ('odometry/filtered','telemetry/navsat_transform_odometry_output'),
        ("gps/filtered","telemetry/gnss/filtered"),
        ('imu','telemetry/imu'),
    ],
    parameters=[{
        "publish_filtered_gps": True,
        "yaw_offset": 1.5707963,
        "zero_altitude": True,
        "use_odometry_yaw": False,
        "magnetic_declination_radians": 0.0383972435, # https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/geomag/calculators/magcalc.shtml
        "datum": [52.00000, 4.00000,0.0]
    }],
)
```

Sample of gnss stream (sensor_msgs/msg/NavSatFix)

```
ros2 topic echo /RAS_TN_DB/telemetry/gnss/fix
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1698245174
    nanosec: 241211074
  frame_id: world
status:
  status: 0
  service: 0
latitude: 52.00141585857095
longitude: 4.3718892860239595
altitude: 0.0
position_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
position_covariance_type: 0
```

Sample of IMU stream (sensor_msgs/msg/Imu)

```
ros2 topic echo /RAS_TN_DB/telemetry/imu
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1698245212
    nanosec: 891237478
  frame_id: world
orientation:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.9750214554943223
  w: 0.22211069610834494
orientation_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
angular_velocity:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
linear_acceleration:
  x: 0.0
  y: 0.0
  z: 0.0
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
---
```

info on the navsat_transfrorm_node:

````
ros2 node info /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node 
/RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node
  Subscribers:
    /RAS_TN_DB/telemetry/gnss/fix: sensor_msgs/msg/NavSatFix
    /RAS_TN_DB/telemetry/imu: sensor_msgs/msg/Imu
    /RAS_TN_DB/telemetry/navsat_transform_odometry_output: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
  Publishers:
    /RAS_TN_DB/gps/filtered: sensor_msgs/msg/NavSatFix
    /RAS_TN_DB/odometry/gps: nav_msgs/msg/Odometry
    /parameter_events: rcl_interfaces/msg/ParameterEvent
    /rosout: rcl_interfaces/msg/Log
    /tf_static: tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage
  Service Servers:
    /RAS_TN_DB/datum: robot_localization/srv/SetDatum
    /RAS_TN_DB/fromLL: robot_localization/srv/FromLL
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/describe_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/DescribeParameters
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/get_parameter_types: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameterTypes
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/get_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/GetParameters
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/list_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/ListParameters
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/set_parameters: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParameters
    /RAS_TN_DB/navsat_transform_node/set_parameters_atomically: rcl_interfaces/srv/SetParametersAtomically
    /RAS_TN_DB/toLL: robot_localization/srv/ToLL
  Service Clients:

  Action Servers:

  Action Clients:
```
````

Comment: I think I have found a similar question here: 

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/64851/how-to-fuse-imu-gps-using-robot-localization?rq=1

I will try to get that to work and will post results here.